# How can I access the User Registry from an EJB in Websphere 6.1

Tags: ejb

I want to access user information from the websphere ldap user registry (e.g. phone no). How can I achieve this?
It's about Websphere Application Server 6.1.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved via Virtual Member Manager (VMM).